# Execute a runnable .jar file from cmd without java -jar

Tags: batch-file, command-line, executable-jar

I want to execute a .jar file from command line using just the .jar file name.
For e.g.
Instead of 
`java -jar <jarname>.jar -a <a> -b <b>`

I want to run
`<jarname> -a <a> -b <b>`

Is it possible. If possible how? I don't want to use batch script, since I am using apache commons cli for command line arguments parsing.

Comment: `java -jar` is meant to execute jars... In OS like Windows, you can have jar so called runnable, but that is, that Windows knows it has to call `java -jar` under the hood...

Comment: Why? It's the best way. Lets you specify the main class and all the dependencies inside the JAR file, instead of on every command line.

Comment: I want to run the executable jar as a standalone command, like mvn for maven.

Comment: Then write a wrapper script ... like "mvn" on Linux or "mvn.bat" on Windows.

Comment: Since you tagged this with `batch-file`: why not writing one?

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the term Wrapper Script

Comment: You haven't answered my question. If you want to write your own command line, you will need to know the main class name and all theJAR files it depends on and where they are. If you embed all that information into the JAR file and use `java -jar`, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible.

No.  It is not possible.

(Well ... if your shell supports a aliases or shell functions, then the user could write one.  For example `alias foo='java -jar foo.jar'`  But that's not really the same.)

For something like this, I would recommend writing a wrapper script.  If you are using a platform with a POSIX compliant shell (sh, bash, etc) then it is not difficult to avoid mangling the command line arguments; e.g.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    java -jar /path/to/foo.jar "$@"
```

or

```
    #!/bin/sh
    java -cp /path/to/foo.jar com.acme.frobnicator.Main "$@"
```

For the record, "mvn" (which you cited as an example) is implemented as a shell script / batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.
What you can do, is write a shell script that does the command you don't want to do, or generate a executable wrapper. In both cases, the solution is OS-dependent. On windows, there is [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), on MacOS, you can create an app (that is a folder with a particular structure).

UPDATE

Actually, creating an app on MacOS is not a solution for using in a command line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that's why I'm trying to answer bit differently to what you asked...

Let say you have `myjar.sh` script, which will "convert"

```
myjar.sh -a <a> -b <b>
```

to

```
java -jar abc.jar -a <a> -b <b>
```

(this is doable, you can see it is [Stephen Cs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640094/384674))

You just have a fear, that it will break your command line arguments parsing. The only possible way is to test and if you find it is not working we can deal with that...